# Setup up GLUT projects in Codeblocks (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, glut, codeblocks

I installed the freeglut3 and freeglut3-dev by apt-get. I want to create a OPENGL GLUT Project in Codeblocks. I was asked the GLUT's location and I entered "/usr" as I found in a tutorial.
But I got the error message:

"The path you entered seems valid, but this wizard
can't locate the following GLUT's library file:
glut in it."

Did I set the right location? What is the right way to setup up such a glut project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem. But I solve the problem  Without creating the project and  run the GLUT program. For that go to compiler and debugger setting and in linker tab and link library libGL.so , libGLU.so, libglut.so  form directory usr/lib by pressing add button.
Now you can include glut.h header and run the project.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I could also do it with CMake. just wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: This is working in 2020 on CodeBlocks 20.03 in Arch Linux

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you already have glut installed.

Open codeblocks and select Opengl project. While inside go to settings -> compiler -> linker settings -> link libraries 
Add glut GL and GLU one by one separately.

Your code should run.

Answer (score 1):

GLEW, GL, GLU, glut

Add these one by one to your project's link libraries after installing them.

Comment: feel free to use a feature called Edit :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: Adding just GL, GLU, glut  (without GLEW) worked for me.        If I try to add GLEW, it shows error that it can't find -lGLEW.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `/usr/local` location if you were executing `./configure`  and installation with default parameters

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Doing two things solved my problem.

1. I added `GL`, `GLU`, `glut` one by one to my project's link libraries. (When I tried to add `GLEW`, it showed error. I didn't add `GLEW` and it didn't cause any problem.)
2. I used the line `#include <GL/glut.h>` to include the header file `glut.h`. `#include <GLUT/glut.h>` or `#include <glut.h>` was showing me fatal error that header file not found.