# Creating GLUT project in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, glut

My problem is that I can't create a glut project in Code::Blocks stated exactly in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234205/setup-up-glut-projects-in-codeblocks-ubuntu-12-04) . But the answer given there doesn't solve my problem. I did `sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev` and `sudo apt-get install binutils-gold` to install GLUT. There is a folder GL in the in`/usr/include`.
In the path glut project creation wizard when I enter `/usr` it complains it cant find GLUTs file. How do I create a Glut Project?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include full header file path in your project.
like this.

> #include "GL\fglut.h"
>
> This above line i have tried on windows and i hope same will work on your system also.
>   and for more information go to this link.
>   [OpenGl building issue](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/faq/)

Comment: This is not my query.